# Swift macOS app: cannot run executable in /usr/local/bin

Tags: swift, macos

### Context

I tried writing a macOS Swift app that launches an executable in `/usr/local/bin` (e.g. Homebrew-installed `/usr/local/bin/cowsay`).

However, this does not work because `/usr/local/bin` is not in the `PATH` environment variable.

Within the app, I tried adding `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` via `setenv`, which also doesn't seem to work.

### Code

Here is a code reproducer with Xcode 12.5 beta 3 (12E5244e):

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

func addPathComponentIfNotSet(_ pathComponent: String) {
  // If path component already exists in PATH, return.
  let path = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PATH"]!
  let pathComponents = path.split(separator: ":")
  if pathComponents.contains(Substring(pathComponent)) {
    return
  }
  // Otherwise, prepend path component to PATH via setenv.
  let newPath = "\(pathComponent):\(path)"
  setenv("PATH", newPath, 1)
  // Print new PATH.
  print("Actual new PATH:", ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PATH"]!)
}

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
  let task = Process()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  task.arguments = args
  task.launch()
  task.waitUntilExit()
  return task.terminationStatus
}

struct DummyContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button("Press me") {
      // Add "/usr/local/bin" to PATH if it doesn't exist.
      // Prints: "Actual new PATH: /usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
      addPathComponentIfNotSet("/usr/local/bin")

      // Test: running "ls" works.
      shell("ls")

      // Error 1: running "cowsay" here fails with "env: cowsay: Operation not permitted".
      shell("cowsay", "Test this")

      // Error 2: running "cowsay" here fails with "The file “cowsay” doesn’t exist".
      let executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/cowsay")
      try! Process.run(
        executableURL,
        arguments: ["Test this too"],
        terminationHandler: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

### Questions

1. Why do attempts to invoke `/usr/local/bin/cowsay` fail?

   - I suspect it is related to security sandboxing.
2. In a Swift macOS app, is it possible to invoke executables within `/usr/local/bin`?

   - Perhaps it's possible if security measures like System Integrity Protection are disabled – other approaches would be ideal.
3. How can I adapt the app to achieve my goal of invoking a local Homebrew-installed binary?

   - One idea is to (a) create a server that can invoke the binary and (b) change the app to be a client sending requests to the server. I wonder if there are more lightweight solutions.

### Accepted solution notes

[Bill's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740757/5365899) worked for me. Here's a screenshot showing the fix – making `Build Settings > Signing > Code Signing Entitlements` empty:

[image: Fix: make Code Signing Entitlements empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is sandboxing.  If this is just for your own use, you could disable sandbox for this application.  To do so, go to target / build settings / signing.  Remove the name of the entitlements file from code signing entitlements.

Comment: Thank you! I added a screenshot to the original post demonstrating the fix.

Comment: rather than remove the name of the entitlements file just toggle the sandbox setting in the entitlements file from yes to no